# Moving from IMAP gmail to Google Apps for domain

Tags: gmail, imap, google-apps

I've got a gmail account that I use to check my IMAP mail from my domain right now and its working OK. I want to move to using google apps for my domain so i dont have to setup accounts etc using my hosting company. Can I do that with my existing google account or do I have to loose my gmail and get a brand new account etc setup again?

Comment: Could you explain in a bit more detail: what do you mean by "using google apps for my domain" - you bought a server from Google and want to install it at "sarahsdomain.com"? "setup accounts etc using my hosting company" - what accounts, where? I find the question hard to understand as it is now.

Comment: Google Apps is a service provided by Google to host domain services like email, web sites, calendars, docs, etc. See google.com/apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been through the process, and although I didn't actually want to tie my @gmail.com account to the Google Apps domain, I didn't see any way this could be done.

I've been very happy with the result, FWIW.

Comment: Thanks! Thats all I really wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question should be for SF or SU.

Anyway, if you want to use name@yourdomain.com, it has nothing to do with your name@gmail.com. They will be independent.

More G.apps FAQ [here](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/faq.html), read "How is Google Apps different from a free @gmail.com account? ".

Comment: After reading `akavel`'s comment on the question, I am questioning the validatity of my answer. The more I read the question, the more I am confused. :P

Comment: Sorry, I might have been a little tipsy when i wrote that.